# Setting up a 4-D contingency table in R from flat, 5 column data.frame with 3 factors

Tags: r, contingency

I have a data frame in **R**. 
The first two columns are my summed frequencies of "Yes" and "No."
The final 3 columns are categorical factors, each with a label.

I am trying to make a 4-D contingency table from this format and I have no idea where to start the process.

My data looks like this:

```
    Sold    Unsold  Label1                   Label2                 Label3
1   3330    32102   AdvancedShopper: Y       TERR_USED: Non-TREE    SPINOFF: N
2   2735    30691   HSEHLD_INCDT_BAND: 0     CLM_FREE_INCDT_CT: 0   SPINOFF: N
3   3350    29485   TERR_USED: Non-TREE      CLM_FREE_INCDT_CT: 0   SPINOFF: N
4   3864    28657   SingleMulti: N           TERR_USED: Non-TREE    SPINOFF: N
5   2691    26355   TERR_USED: Non-TREE      HSEHLD_INCDT_BAND: 0   CLM_FREE_INCDT_CT: 0
6   2396    25884   TERR_USED: Non-TREE      HSEHLD_INCDT_BAND: 0   SPINOFF: N
7   2738    25172   Channel: Owned Agency    TERR_USED: Non-TREE    SPINOFF: N
8   3203    24425   TERR_USED: Non-TREE      FULL_CVG_FLG: Y        SPINOFF: N
9   2781    24163   SingleMulti: N           CLM_FREE_INCDT_CT: 0   SPINOFF: N
10  1950    22371   AdvancedShopper: Y       CLM_FREE_INCDT_CT: 0   SPINOFF: N
11  2644    21528   TERR_USED: Non-TREE      FULL_CVG_FLG: N        SPINOFF: N
12  2278    21736   Channel: Owned Agency    SingleMulti: N         SPINOFF: N
13  2324    21648   SingleMulti: N           HSEHLD_INCDT_BAND: 0   CLM_FREE_INCDT_CT: 0
14  3108    20780   Channel: Prudent         TERR_USED: Non-TREE    SPINOFF: N
15  2491    21216   TERR_USED: Non-TREE      PRIOR_BI: High         SPINOFF: N
```

I began with 8 columns: 3 Categories + 3 Values for each category + (1) number of Quotes written, and (1) number of sales on those Quotes = 8. I concatenated the respective category and value strings to form the three columns above. I have 19 categories, each category has its own number of attributes between 2 and 6. Sorting will put the respective columns in order, but not necessarily form the 4-D boxes for each combination of 3 categories and the respective Yes (Sold) and No (Unsold). The mean rate of sales is 11.4% and I would like to get the frequencies into shape to run Chi2 tests on these four-way contingencies to identify the combinations that create the strongest outliers from the mean. I have 80046 combinations, essentially (19 choose 3) with each of those three choices having their respective buckets, for example Row 1 is from a 4-D table of 16 cells (2 attr x 2 attr x 2 attr x [Y,N]), Row 2 is from a 4-D table of 96 cells (4 attr x 6 attr x 2 attr x [Y,N])... etc.

I'm unsure how to get this data into a format to start using the `table()` and `xtabs()` functions and thus the `chi2.test`. (Should I go back to the step before I concatenated the categories and values?)

I new to R, but I know it's supposed to be much better at programming for these large arrays. I don't have access to SPSS, but I do have access to SAS (also new in that) if there's something easier to try there...

Any sort of direction is a big help.

------------------- Desired output? reply ---------------------
Well, the `table` command takes a data.frame from

```
Category 1       Category 2       Category 3       Y/N
```

...into contingency table format, right? But I already have my Yes's and No's in a frequency format with the three categories listed as such.

Do I need to change to this single instance format and explode my 80046 row table into millions of rows? Or is there a way to initiate the `table` command with the frequencies of Yes and No already tabulated in two columns?

Comment: Please post the expected output for your sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case you can create a variable which gives a percentage of Yes over Yes+No: See whether this works for you (assume your data is sample).

```
mytab <- xtabs((100*Sold/(Sold+Unsold))~Label1+Label2+Label3, data=sample)

  > mytab
, , Label3 = CLM_FREE_INCDT_CT: 0

                       Label2
Label1                  CLM_FREE_INCDT_CT: 0 FULL_CVG_FLG: N FULL_CVG_FLG: Y HSEHLD_INCDT_BAND: 0 PRIOR_BI: High SingleMulti: N
  AdvancedShopper: Y                0.000000        0.000000        0.000000             0.000000       0.000000       0.000000
  Channel: Owned Agency             0.000000        0.000000        0.000000             0.000000       0.000000       0.000000
  Channel: Prudent                  0.000000        0.000000        0.000000             0.000000       0.000000       0.000000
  HSEHLD_INCDT_BAND: 0              0.000000        0.000000        0.000000             0.000000       0.000000       0.000000
  SingleMulti: N                    0.000000        0.000000        0.000000             9.694644       0.000000       0.000000
  TERR_USED: Non-TREE               0.000000        0.000000        0.000000             9.264615       0.000000       0.000000
                       Label2
Label1                  TERR_USED: Non-TREE
  AdvancedShopper: Y               0.000000
  Channel: Owned Agency            0.000000
  Channel: Prudent                 0.000000
  HSEHLD_INCDT_BAND: 0             0.000000
  SingleMulti: N                   0.000000
  TERR_USED: Non-TREE              0.000000

, , Label3 = SPINOFF: N

                       Label2
Label1                  CLM_FREE_INCDT_CT: 0 FULL_CVG_FLG: N FULL_CVG_FLG: Y HSEHLD_INCDT_BAND: 0 PRIOR_BI: High SingleMulti: N
  AdvancedShopper: Y                8.017762        0.000000        0.000000             0.000000       0.000000       0.000000
  Channel: Owned Agency             0.000000        0.000000        0.000000             0.000000       0.000000       9.486133
  Channel: Prudent                  0.000000        0.000000        0.000000             0.000000       0.000000       0.000000
  HSEHLD_INCDT_BAND: 0              8.182253        0.000000        0.000000             0.000000       0.000000       0.000000
  SingleMulti: N                   10.321407        0.000000        0.000000             0.000000       0.000000       0.000000
  TERR_USED: Non-TREE              10.202528       10.938276       11.593311             8.472419      10.507445       0.000000
                       Label2
Label1                  TERR_USED: Non-TREE
  AdvancedShopper: Y               9.398284
  Channel: Owned Agency            9.810104
  Channel: Prudent                13.010717
  HSEHLD_INCDT_BAND: 0             0.000000
  SingleMulti: N                  11.881553
  TERR_USED: Non-TREE              0.000000

Call: xtabs(formula = (100 * Sold/(Sold + Unsold)) ~ Label1 + Label2 + 
    Label3, data = l)
Number of cases in table: 150.7815 
Number of factors: 3 
Test for independence of all factors:
    Chisq = 412.2, df = 71, p-value = 1.48e-49
    Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

Comment: The `table` function takes

Comment: It works... but now I have to interact with the resulting values which are in a 79x97x160 table... Not really sure how to do this yet, and if the number of Sold and Unsold Quotes can be weighted into these Chi2 values in some other way...

Comment: I didn't get what you are saying; how do you have 79*97*160 tables?